# Stuck in Hades in Zork

Tags: zork

I was really far in the game and went to the cellar to then being eaten by something (I forgot) and got transported to Hades.

I read a thing saying to go to an altar and pray but I don't know where it is. You start off with being in front of a bell which you can't pick up (your hand goes through it). The only way you can go is South (or East) and get to the candles, matchbook and black book. You can't read the book, light candles or light a match. You can only go back to where you started, AKA going North. What do I do? I'd rather not start over.

Answer (score 1):

The route from the Entrance to Hades to the altar is:

1. Up to the first cave
2. North three times to the Round Room
3. Southeast to the Engravings Cave
4. East to the dome, where you automatically float down to the Torch Room.
5. Down to the temple.
6. South to the altar. You can then pray there to come back to life.

Also note that it's generally advisable in Interactive Fiction games like Zork to save frequently, so you can just restore when you die rather that worrying about the extra life mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I was able to find the Altar. When I prayed, I resurrected to a forest.

I couldnt interact with the book, candle, nor bell though when I was dead. I'm just winging it now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: _How_ did you find the altar?